# Не могу достучаться до приложения

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot

Написал веб приложение на spring boot.
Через Intelij Idea (встроеный в spring boot tomcat) все запускается и работает. Хочу попробовать запустить именно через внешний томкат чтоб в дальнейшем развернуть на работе по локальной сети. Не могу достучаться до своего приложения. На стартовую страницу томката заходит по адрессу http://localhost:8080/. А дальше ну ни как.
Что только не пробовал.

pom и все остальное можно посмотреть [здесь](https://github.com/OnlyTarg/PeopleDB)

Comment: А зачем спринг бут если Вы используете **внешний** томкат?

Comment: Как мне его запустить без Intelij Idea?  Думал установить tomcat на машине, кинуть туда war и запустить сервер. Но с другой стороны tomcat уже встроен... Может просто в jar собрать и tomcat будет запускаться при запуске jar? А как тогда остановить сервер.  Просто руки опускаются. Неужели это мне одному все так сложно....

Comment: Вариант который вы описали (java -jar app.jar) и есть тот самый способ запустить спринг бут приложение, остановить его - ctrl+c в окне консоли где оно запущено

Comment: собрал jar. Запустил. Теперь при переходе на  http://localhost:8080/ выдает  Whitelabel Error Page. Приложение должно ж выдавать стартовую страницу TomCat???

Comment: А должно открыться это ? https://github.com/OnlyTarg/PeopleDB/blob/1e1a3a43ca91f5c0ffd081850236f87d7021968e/src/main/java/com/person/demo/controllers/PersonController.java#L28

Comment: Ну насколько я понимаю .... должно выдавать стартовую страницу Тома. А дальше уже соответственно маппинг контроллеров. (/index.html) и т.д.